# Mouting with cifs

Tags: linux, mount, cifs

Im writing a script to create mounts. The system command I use is:

```
sudo /bin/mount -soft -t smbfs -o username='{username}',password='{password}' {server_path} {local_path}
```

It works a treat, but here's the problem....

If an username/password is not valid. I can tidyup using unmount command. However, it corrupts the other mounts to the same {server_path} on the box.

Any ideas how I can stop this from happening?

Thanks

Jen

Answer (score 1):

In general, the smbfs module in the Linux kernel is deprecated in favor of the cifs module. So the first thing I'd try would be to switch to that one, and see if that fixes your issue.